# MVC Ajax get with complex type always getting null values

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to make a get request to a method from my controller, but I'm always getting null values inside the parameter location.

My model Is:

```
public class UserLocation
{
    public decimal Lat { get; set; }
    public decimal Long { get; set; }

    public UserLocation() { }
    public UserLocation(decimal lat, decimal lon)
    {
        Lat = lat;
        Long = lon;
    }
}
```

The method from my controller is

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult getLocations([FromUri]UserLocation userLocation, int perimeter)
    {
        return Json(LocationsHandler.getLocations(userLocation, perimeter));
    }
```

And my ajax call

```
function getLocations() {
    var loc = { location: { Lat: "0", Long: "11" } };
    var range = 22;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Location/getLocations',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'application/json;',
        data: { location: loc, perimeter: range },
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result.Data.length);
            self.Parametros(result.Data);
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
```

The method is called and in the second parameter(perimeter) i get the correct value but not in my complex type method.

Does somebody knows what can be the problem?

Comment: `data: JSON.stringify({ userLocation: { Lat: "0", Long: "11" }, perimeter: range }),` (and remove `[FromUri]`)

Comment: I tried your solution and the problem remains, i Tried to add the perimeter into the UserLocation class and still the same.

Comment: Just noticed you have other issues as well. You can simply make it `data: { Lat: 0, Long: 11, perimeter: 22},` but its a GET method so you must also specify `return Json(...., JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to **Stringify** at client side and **Deserialize** at server side.

**Client Side :**

```
JSON.stringify(loc);
```

**Server Side :**

```
public JsonResult getLocations(JsonObject json, int perimeter)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var c = js.Deserialize<MyClass>(json);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `JsonRequestBehavior` to `AllowGet`

```
return Json(LocationsHandler.getLocations(userLocation, perimeter),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Thanks i added it but i think this is to allow json return.

Answer (score 0):

Check and tell if it does not work. I think you are missing contentType and wrong dataType.

```
         $.ajax({
            url: '/Location/getLocations',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({ location: loc, perimeter: range }),
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result.Data.length);
                self.Parametros(result.Data);
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
```